# Protecting private member return by reference from accidental reassignment

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants

I have the following function prototype:

```
virtual CBuffer& GetData(unsigned int& samples, unsigned int& stride);
```

This returns a reference to a CBuffer object that is a private member of my class.

The problem is that if the following is written, the internal private member that the method returns will be reassigned.

```
CBuffer& CPlug::ProcessData(unsigned int& samples, unsigned int& stride)
{
  /* get the data from the source */
  CBuffer& buffer = m_source.GetData(samples, stride);

  if (m_postProcess)
    buffer = PostProcess(buffer, samples, stride);

  return buffer;
}
```

Obviously this can be fixed by doing the following:

```
CBuffer& CPlug::ProcessData(unsigned int& samples, unsigned int& stride)
{
  /* get the data from the source */
  CBuffer* buffer = &m_source.GetData(samples, stride);

  if (m_postProcess)
    buffer = &PostProcess(*buffer, samples, stride);

  return *buffer;
}
```

But I want to know if there is some way to prevent this, possibly through some use of `const` that I am unaware of?

At this point I am of the opinion that I should just convert to using pointers, but it would be nice to know if it could be done.

Comment: How is PostProcess declared? It looks a little like you are taking the address of a temporary ***or*** PostProcess has the exact same problem. (And `GetData` by the way)

Comment: PostProcess is declared much the same way but it is not the problem, the reassignment of `buffer` is.

Comment: It's **only** a problem because `GetData` and/or `PostProcess` return references in the first place.

Comment: @sehe - I understand that, I am asking if there is an elegant solution other then reverting to pointers? It is fine if there is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a sample says more than a thousand words, potentially: **[see it live](http://ideone.com/eP8VRX)**

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

typedef std::vector<int> CBuffer;

static CBuffer& PostProcess(CBuffer& data)  { 
    for(auto& el : data)
        el /= 2;
    return data;
}

struct CSource
{
    CSource() : _data(std::make_shared<CBuffer>(10)) {}

    std::shared_ptr<CBuffer>       GetData()       { return _data; }
    std::shared_ptr<const CBuffer> GetData() const { return _data; }

  private:
    std::shared_ptr<CBuffer> _data;
};

struct CPlug
{
    CPlug(bool postProcess = true) : m_postProcess(postProcess) { }

    std::shared_ptr<const CBuffer> ProcessData() const
    {
        /* get the data from the source, implicitely const */
        auto buffer = m_source.GetData();

        if (!m_postProcess)
            return buffer;

        // clone!
        auto clone = *buffer;
        return std::make_shared<CBuffer>(PostProcess(clone));
    }

  private:
    bool    m_postProcess;
    CSource m_source;
};

int main()
{
    CPlug intance;
}
```